# How do I get vite to build entire project instead of just the index.html page?

Tags: build, production, vite

I am new to vite and I can't figure out how to get it to build my entire project instead of just my index.html page. I run "npm run build" and every time it just does that index.html but in npm run dev it works fine. I have all my files on the same level as in the picture. How do I resolve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Create a **vite.config.js** file at the root of project and put this in it

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('vite')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: './index.html',
        about: './about.html',
        shaderOne: './shaderOne.html',
        // ...
        // List all files you want in your build
      }
    }
  }
})
```

If not, you will need to install vite locally. You can install it using `npm install vite`
See [this documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#multi-page-app)

Comment: I love you very much

Comment: I am trying to also include a css "library" and vite is telling my to `build.rollupOptions.external`. I am adding this to my config file but it seems my syntax is incorrect. What do I need to fix?        build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      external: {
          style: './style.css',
      },

Comment: im rebuilding the vite app nvm

Comment: @Yerbs Maybe you could see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67696920/vite-rollup-failed-to-resolve-build-error) or ask another question.