# Failure to deploy more than one page to firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I am using the firebase with vite framework for my web poject. Once configured and installed all the necessary programs followed by the actuall production process of the site I was ready to deploy. Once the deployment command `Firebase deploy` was made, only the index.html, and the respective scripts and styles that are responsible to render a functional page, were depoyed to firebase. I intend to make a multi page site yet I am prevented by this occurrence.
The following is my currently test firebase.json file:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "source": "hosting",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "us-east1"
    }
  }
}
```

My pucblic directory, as was designed in the firebase configuration, is hosting. All my desired html pages are inside this directory and my scripts are in a child directory from hosting.

Multiple attempts of alteration were made in the json file, however still there were no success.
The following is the log result in the build_log.txt file from the `npm run build > build_log.txt` command:

```
hosting@0.0.0 build
tsc && vite build 

[36mvite v5.0.5 [32mbuilding for production...[36m[39m
transforming...
[32mÔ£ô[39m 21 modules transformed.
rendering chunks...
computing gzip size...
[2mdist/[22m[32mindex.html                       [39m[1m[2m  3.05 kB[22m[1m[22m[2m Ôöé gzip:   1.21 kB[22m
[2mdist/[22m[32massets/wemarkIcon-Dz6Y6-tA.jpeg  [39m[1m[2m 56.12 kB[22m[1m[22m
[2mdist/[22m[35massets/index-tU7vuZiw.css        [39m[1m[2m  5.49 kB[22m[1m[22m[2m Ôöé gzip:   1.82 kB[22m
[2mdist/[22m[36massets/index-nwg7Oc3M.js         [39m[1m[2m454.80 kB[22m[1m[22m[2m Ôöé gzip: 106.53 kB[22m
[32mÔ£ô built in 1.80s[39m
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am deeply sorry for my misconception, and ignorance in this matter. It was not a Firebase problem, rather it was a Vite misconfiguration. There was the necessity to determine in a `vite.config.ts` file if there were other files and where to rewrite those.

I could find the information and correct guidance in this [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71544439/how-do-i-get-vite-to-build-entire-project-instead-of-just-the-index-html-page) and this [documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#multi-page-app)

I really apreciate the assistant from those involved. My sincere thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Vite is not a "framework".  It is a "development system" that supports many different frameworks (React, Vue, Angular, etc....)

Vite is used to run the code when you are in "development mode", and it is used to bundle the code into a deployable distribution set when you run `vite build` (which is typically what you get when you run `npm run build` or `yarn build`....see the "scripts" section of your `package.json`).  Since you indicated that the name of the output folder is "dist" then in your firebase.json you want to have:

```
{
  ....
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    ...
  }
}
```

Typically what you want to do to deploy a Vite-backed application is to run `vite build` and then deploy the ***results of the build*** to Firebase Hosting.  To do that you would set the `hosting.public` property in your `firebase.json` to be the directory where the build output goes from your Vite....that is typically a directory at the root of your project named `dist` or `build`.

Once you build (`npm run build`) then you deploy (`firebase deploy --only hosting`).

Comment: I did proceed with your instructions, which produced no change whatsoever. After running `npm run build`, as mentioned in my package.json. That triggered `tsc && vite build`. This command create the dist directory and added the built files, yet it only had the index.html file in it. 
I need to build multiple files to deploy to firebase.
I am happy to give more information to help solve this issue, if needed.

Comment: After running `npm run build` you only got a single file in the `dist` directory?  Maybe you could run the command, capture the console output to a file, then share that output (`npm run build > build_log.txt`)

Comment: I added the requested info inside the main post. Thank you

Comment: So it is adding several files to the build output folder, including in a subdirectory named "assets".  Your JS code has been bundled into a file named  `assets/index-nwg7Oc3M.js` which is 484 kb in size.  That file is your React code.  What is the value of `hosting.public` in your `firebase.json`?  It should be `"public": "dist"`

Comment: Wait, which framework are you using with Vite?  What does your `vite.config.js` indicate: Vanilla, Vue, React, Preact, Lit, Svelte, Solid, Qwik, ..... ?